# How to scroll textarea elements inside an iframe element

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, scroll, textarea

I have the following HTML:

```html
<iframe id="screenshare" ref="screenshare" class="fullScreen2"></iframe>
```

I am filling the `<iframe>` element **dynamically** using JavaScript with the following function:

```js
function receiveMasterBody(body, width, height) {
    let iframe = document.getElementById('screenshare');
    let iframeWindow = iframe.contentWindow;

    $("#screenshare").width(width);
    $("#screenshare").height(height);           

    iframeWindow.document.body.innerHTML = body;
}
```

The `body` parameter of the function `receiveMasterBody` contains multiple `<textarea>` elements and each and every one of them is marked with `'data-scroll'` attribute in case a scroll is available, either `scrollTop` or `scrollLeft`. This **attribute** is entirely **custom** and is used to indicate where the current scroll of the textarea element should be(only for information). Example of `<textarea>` tag containing the `'data-scroll'` attribute. Displaying a fraction of the `body` parameter to show example textarea that should be scrolled:

```html
<textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea2" rows="3" data-scroll="3233,0" style="margin: 0px 402px 0px 0px; height: 301px; width: 307px;">... A lot of content here ...</textarea>
```

So check the `'data-scroll'` attribute with value `"3233,0"`, indicating `scrollTop = 3233` and `scrollLeft = 0`.

---

What I want to do is to scroll all `<textarea>` elements marked with `'data-scroll'` attribute to the desired scroll values.

### What I tried?

Inside my `receiveMasterBody` function, exactly after the code there:

```js
let jBody = $(iframeWindow.document.body.innerHTML);
let scrollElems = jBody.find('[data-scroll]');
for (let a = 0; a < scrollElems.length; a++) {
    let scrollPositions = scrollElems[a].getAttribute('data-scroll').split(',').map(x => +x);
    console.log(scrollPositions);
    //$(scrollElems[a]).scroll({ top: scrollPositions[0], left: scrollPositions[1] });
    $(scrollElems[a]).scrollTop = scrollPositions[0];
}
```

This line `console.log(scrollPositions);` returns the following for example:
[image]

I am getting the scroll values correctly, but the **scrolling** is **not** working. I've tried with the `//$(scrollElems[a]).scroll({ top: scrollPositions[0], left: scrollPositions[1] });` line as well - no results as well.

I get the correct values, I just couldn't scroll the `<textarea>` inside the `<iframe>` element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`innerHTML` it's just HTML text code, it's not a reference to any object inside the `iframe`. For the `jBody`, you need to get the `body` of `$(iframeWindow.document.body)` and not the HTML `$(iframeWindow.document.body.innerHTML)`:

```js
// Get the body and NOT body.innerHTML
let jBody = $(iframeWindow.document.body);

let scrollElems = jBody.find('[data-scroll]');
for (let a = 0; a < scrollElems.length; a++) {
    let scrollPositions = scrollElems[a].getAttribute('data-scroll').split(',').map(x => +x);
    console.log(scrollPositions);

    $(scrollElems[a]).scrollTop(scrollPositions[0]);
    // OR
    // $(scrollElems[a]).scroll({ top: scrollPositions[0], left: scrollPositions[1] });
}
```

Check this working [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/jquery-scroll-iframe-textarea?file=index.html).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It did the trick. I was so close to getting it right. In an hour I award the bounty. :)